# calibration according to Kuleshov

Tags: regression, neural-networks, calibration

i was reading this paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00263.pdf in which Kuleshov gives a definition of a well calibrated neural network in a regression task

[image]

[image]

I would like to ask one thing:
why does he makes a special cases for when $x_t,y_t$ are i.i.d. realizations of random variables $X, Y \sim \mathbb{P}$? when we do regression don't we always assume that  both the independent and dependent variables are jointly distributed? also why is a sufficient condition?

Comment: @BenReiniger but since   X represents the input given to the neural network  by the user, what would it be its distribution? i am superconfused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have realizations $(x_t, y_t)$ from their joint distribution $\mathbb P$ that are not independent. E.g., you could decide to choose $x_{t+1}$ as a function of $y_t$.

As to why Equation (4) is sufficient for Equation (3):
I think he just wants to say that if he uses the quantile function of the $Y$-marginal of $\mathbb P$ as the forcaster $H(X)$, i.e. $H(X)$ would be the same for all $X$, then it would be calibrated. But that is by definition: provided you sample i.i.d. from $\mathbb P$, you will for $t\to\infty$ get relative frequencies that converge to the marginal $Y$-distribution.

Comment: sorry but i  am confused. 1) in a neural network  the output y is always dependent from the input x given by the user, so $y_t$ is always dependent on $x_t$, what do you mean with picking $x_{t+1}$ in place of $x_t$? 2) from where did you understand that he was referring to the Y-marginal distribution for the forecaster? from the fact the he uses Capital $X$ rather than $x$?

Comment: i have found another article where a different author provide a summary https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.11659.pdf and he says it's equivalent, not sufficient....

Comment: If I understand the author correctly, then $\mathbb P$ is the joint distribution of two random variables $X, Y$ and that is independent of any NN. You can decide to train a NN on $\mathbb P$, but $\mathbb P$ is not related to any NN. And in that $\mathbb P$, you have $Y \sim \mathbb P(Y|X)$ and in regression, you want the mean thereof to be predicted for each $x$ by your NN, that's why you train the NN.

Comment: If I understand the author correctly, then his sample $\{(x_t, y_t)\}$ is indexed by integers $t$. Now, the samples are supposed to be iid. But if you change the sampling scheme in the way I described, the elements of the sample will not be independent anymore. Just take the sample element $(x_t, y_t)$ of step $t$ and then obtain the next sample element, the one for $t+1$, as follows: choose $x_{t+1}$ as some appropriate function $f$ of $y_t$, $x_{t+1} = f(y_t)$. Next, e.g. sample $y_{t+1}$ from $\mathbb P(Y|X=x_{t+1})$. Then your sample is not independent anymore.

Comment: Your second point: I think that because of Equation (4) and the line immediately following that.

Comment: Please, don't extend your question by asking me to read additional papers not mentioned in the original question. Rather, ask a new question.